# How to share a private google doc with an appengine app

Tags: google-app-engine, google-oauth, google-fusion-tables

I have a document (its actually a fusion table) stored in my private Google Drive.

I would like to share the document with a web application running on google app engine. I would like to enter the link to the document into the app and have it read the document using the fusion-table API.

However, I don't want ro publish the document to be visible to anyone who has the link.

Can the application access the document with its own service account. 
Each App Engine app has a Service Account, like: 123456789@developer.gserviceaccount.com

If I share my document with the service account, then can the app 'read' the document?

If yes, then are there any risks to the system admin from publishing the service account's email address so users can share with the app but not anyone with the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can share with the application's service account, and the application will be able to read the file.

I do not see any risk related to sharing the service account's email, but it might be a bit tedious for the user to copy/paste a complicated email into the Fusion Tables UI.

Comment: Thanks, I wil try it out. I found a related q&a which seems to backup your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14511158/google-appengine-to-fusion-tables-with-service-accounts?rq=1