# How to create a fusion table using the google-python-api

Tags: google-app-engine, google-fusion-tables, google-api-python-client

Using the [API Client Library for Python](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/) what is the syntax for creating a new fusion table belonging to a Python AppEngine app's, service account?

Having created the service, I am not sure what interface methods it provides and can't find any documentation or examples other than ones that query existing tables, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14511158/google-appengine-to-fusion-tables-with-service-accounts):

```
service.query().sql(sql=
"INSERT INTO %s (Temperature,Date) values(%s,'%s')" %
(tableid,value1,now)).execute()
```

There is an [example](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/using#CreatingTables) for the REST API that I am trying to adapt.

```
fusion_columns = {
        "name": "Insects",
        "columns": [
            {
                "name": "Species",
                "type": "STRING"
            },
            {
                "name": "Elevation",
                "type": "NUMBER"
            },
            {
                "name": "Year",
                "type": "DATETIME"
            }
        ],
        "description": "Insect Tracking Information.",
        "isExportable": "true"
    }

    service = build('fusiontables', 'v2', credentials=credentials, )

    newtable = service.table().insert()
    newtable = service.table().insert(fusion_columns)
```

Neither of the last two lines are correct.

Would be better to switch to the REST-API and loose the Python API wrapper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the [reference](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/fusiontables/v2/python/latest/fusiontables_v2.table.html#insert.) here

newtable = service.table().insert(body=*)

Comment: that should be `service.table().insert(body=*)`