# oauth required for creating a fusion table?

Tags: google-fusion-tables

This is more a theorical question than a practical one. Closely related to this one: [Fusion Table and Google Service Accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10338497/fusion-table-and-google-service-accounts). I'm trying to make an app that creates, populates and queries some Fusion tables. As far as I understand from the doc, if tables are all public, only the API key is needed.

Otherwise, supposing I ought to use Oauth, I don't want any user to authenticate anything, since this is going to be App owned data - Google Fusion Tables (no users involved). Looks like I have to create a Service Account for this:

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount

I already created one, got the private key and everything, but this is where I get lost, and the docs don't seem to help...what should I do with this private key? I'd love to see a step by step example of using this private key to access fusion tables...

Thanks!
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, I've got to answer my own question, but here it goes if anyone has the same problem. Regarding access to Fusion Tables, there are basically two ways of doing this:

- **API key to access Fusion Tables public tables (only with read
  permissions)**

This means that if your app only needs to access Fusion Tables marked as "public", it should suffice. For instance, the next snippet shows how to do this (using [JERSEY](http://jersey.java.net/) to make the REST request). I have obviously removed my API key, just use your one:

```
        Client client = Client.create();
    String g = null;
    try {
        g = URIUtil.encodeQuery("https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=SELECT * FROM 1V5-SgN2tbPHrzFdsapEI541yTD9I3p7NQIXqeSo&key=[your key here]");
    } 
    catch (URIException e) {    
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    WebResource webResource = client.resource(g);
    String s = webResource.get(String.class);
    Logger.debug(s);
```

- **Service Account to create, populate, query and delete Fusion Tables**

If you need the above, and you can't have a real user interfere in the process, you need a Service Account, that can be easily created in the [API console manager](https://code.google.com/apis/console). My recommendation for this is to check out the whole project tree of samples that google provides [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs), and try some of the service account ones: fusion tables, plus, and storage. I found them very enlighting for this.

You can find more related info in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16429828/how-to-authenticate-in-fusion-tables-with-oauth-v2/16441567#16441567).

So, it depends in the level of access you require, but most of the times, you gonna need Oauth authentication.

Hope this helps someone.

Regards,
Alex